# How do you find the dimensions of a "display: none" element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some child elements inside a div that gets the CSS `display: none` applied to it and I want to find out what the child element dimensions are. How can I do this?

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/h9b17vyk/)

```js
var o = document.getElementById('output');
var wmd1 = document.getElementById('whats-my-dims1');
var wmd2 = document.getElementById('whats-my-dims2');
o.innerHTML = 'wmd1: "' + wmd1.clientWidth + '", "' + wmd1.clientHeight + '", wmd2: "' + wmd2.clientWidth + '", "' + wmd2.clientHeight + '"';
```

```css
#some-hidden-div{
  display: none;
}
.whats-my-dims{
  width: 69px;
  height: 42px;
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div id='output'>Processing... :p</div>
<div id='some-hidden-div'>
  <div class='whats-my-dims' id='whats-my-dims1'></div>
</div>
<div class='whats-my-dims' id='whats-my-dims2'></div>
```

I can only use pure JavaScript (no jQuery).

I can't change top/left/right/bottom/transform/translate/etc because this is going to be part of an animated sprite sheet custom component that can have child elements.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `window.getComputedStyle()`

```js
var o = document.getElementById('output');
var wmd1 = document.getElementById('whats-my-dims1');
var wmd2 = document.getElementById('whats-my-dims2');
o.innerHTML = 'wmd1: "' + window.getComputedStyle(wmd1).getPropertyValue("width") 
+ '", "' 
+ window.getComputedStyle(wmd1).getPropertyValue("height") 
+ '", wmd2: "' 
+ window.getComputedStyle(wmd2).getPropertyValue("width") + '", "' 
+ window.getComputedStyle(wmd2).getPropertyValue("height") + '"';
```

```css
#some-hidden-div{
  display: none;
}
.whats-my-dims{
  display:block;
  width: 69px;
  height: 42px;
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div id='output'>
  Processing... :p
</div>
<div>
  Sooo... How do I get the width and height of whats-my-dims1?
</div>
<div id='some-hidden-div'>
  <div class='whats-my-dims' id='whats-my-dims1'></div>
</div>
<div class='whats-my-dims' id='whats-my-dims2'></div>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/h9b17vyk/3/

Comment: This works, too - it depends on the `display` value of the children and whether or not they have fixed dimensions.

Comment: @BoltClock Another approach would be, if they exist, to retrieve `link` and `style` elements and `style` attribute text matched to selector

Comment: Doesn't work for elements with dynamic dimensions. All it will return is `auto`.

Comment: doesn't work if width is set to max-width either. In this case it returns 'auto'

Comment: getComputedStyle function is good but not working for get width of hidden element

Answer (score 16):

You cannot find the dimensions of an element with `display: none` but you can turn on the display, get the dimensions and then set it back to hidden. This wouldn't cause any visual differences.

```js
var o = document.getElementById('output');
var wmd1 = document.getElementById('whats-my-dims1');
var someHiddenDiv = document.querySelector('#some-hidden-div');
someHiddenDiv.style.display = 'block';
var wmd2 = document.getElementById('whats-my-dims2');
o.innerHTML = 'wmd1: "' + wmd1.clientWidth + '", "' + wmd1.clientHeight + '", wmd2: "' + wmd2.clientWidth + '", "' + wmd2.clientHeight + '"';
someHiddenDiv.style.display = 'none';
```

```css
#some-hidden-div {
  display: none;
}
.whats-my-dims {
  width: 75px;
  height: 42px;
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div id='output'>
  Processing... :p
</div>
<div>
  Sooo... How do I get the width and height of whats-my-dims1?
</div>
<div id='some-hidden-div'>
  <div class='whats-my-dims' id='whats-my-dims1'></div>
</div>
<div class='whats-my-dims' id='whats-my-dims2'></div>
```

---

Note that in some cases setting the `display: none` back with inline styles might cause unnecessary trouble (because inline styles take precedence over CSS selectors unless they have `!important`). In such cases you might want to remove the style attribute itself totally.

In the below snippet, you would see that the addition of `.show` class has no effect because the inline `display: none` is taking precedence.

```js
var o = document.getElementById('output');
var wmd1 = document.getElementById('whats-my-dims1');
var someHiddenDiv = document.querySelector('#some-hidden-div');
someHiddenDiv.style.display = 'block';
var wmd2 = document.getElementById('whats-my-dims2');
o.innerHTML = 'wmd1: "' + wmd1.clientWidth + '", "' + wmd1.clientHeight + '", wmd2: "' + wmd2.clientWidth + '", "' + wmd2.clientHeight + '"';
someHiddenDiv.style.display = 'none';


var btn = document.querySelector('#show');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  someHiddenDiv.classList.add('show');
});
```

```css
#some-hidden-div {
  display: none;
}
.whats-my-dims {
  width: 75px;
  height: 42px;
  background-color: #f00;
}
#some-hidden-div.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id='output'>
  Processing... :p
</div>
<div>
  Sooo... How do I get the width and height of whats-my-dims1?
</div>
<div id='some-hidden-div'>
  <div class='whats-my-dims' id='whats-my-dims1'>Some text</div>
</div>
<div class='whats-my-dims' id='whats-my-dims2'></div>

<button id='show'>Show the hidden div</button>
```

whereas in the below snippet, it doesn't cause any problem because the inline style is totally removed.

```js
var o = document.getElementById('output');
var wmd1 = document.getElementById('whats-my-dims1');
var someHiddenDiv = document.querySelector('#some-hidden-div');
someHiddenDiv.style.display = 'block';
var wmd2 = document.getElementById('whats-my-dims2');
o.innerHTML = 'wmd1: "' + wmd1.clientWidth + '", "' + wmd1.clientHeight + '", wmd2: "' + wmd2.clientWidth + '", "' + wmd2.clientHeight + '"';
someHiddenDiv.style = null;


var btn = document.querySelector('#show');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  someHiddenDiv.classList.add('show');
});
```

```css
#some-hidden-div {
  display: none;
}
.whats-my-dims {
  width: 75px;
  height: 42px;
  background-color: #f00;
}
#some-hidden-div.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id='output'>
  Processing... :p
</div>
<div>
  Sooo... How do I get the width and height of whats-my-dims1?
</div>
<div id='some-hidden-div'>
  <div class='whats-my-dims' id='whats-my-dims1'>Some text</div>
</div>
<div class='whats-my-dims' id='whats-my-dims2'></div>

<button id='show'>Show the hidden div</button>
```

Comment: I am going with window.getComputedStyle answer because I am not guaranteed to know if it's just the parent 'output' that is going to be 'display: none'.  It could be the parent of the parent of the parent (etc) that has 'display: none' on it.'  It looks like window.getComputedStyle doesn't care if a parent has 'display: none' on it and that is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 11):

You can't get dimensions of an element with `display: none`, because since it's hidden, it doesn't take any space, so it has no dimensions. The same apply to its children.

You can instead make the element visible for a while, check the child dimensions and make the element invisible back. As pointed by @JanDvorak:

> Browsers don't repaint while synchronous Javascript is running, so the element should never appear on-screen.

Example code:

```
var o = document.getElementById('output');
var wmd1 = document.getElementById('whats-my-dims1');
var wmd2 = document.getElementById('whats-my-dims2');
var hiddenDiv = document.getElementById("some-hidden-div");
hiddenDiv.style.display = "block";
o.innerHTML = 'wmd1: "' + wmd1.clientWidth + '", "' + wmd1.clientHeight + '", wmd2: "' + wmd2.clientWidth + '", "' + wmd2.clientHeight + '"';
hiddenDiv.style.display = "";
```

See [demo on JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h9b17vyk/2/).

Comment: Browsers don't repaint while synchronous Javascript is running, so the element should never appear on-screen. I suspect the spec doesn't even _allow_ browsers to repaint the screen while Javascript is running.

Comment: I am going with window.getComputedStyle answer because I am not guaranteed to know if it's just the parent 'output' that is going to be 'display: none'.  It could be the parent of the parent of the parent (etc) that has 'display: none' on it.'  It looks like window.getComputedStyle doesn't care if a parent has 'display: none' on it and that is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

**For someone who need this to implement a context menu or hint window:**

The `getComputedStyle()` isn't seem to work on elements that have dynamic width/height. All you get is `auto`.

My approach was to set `visibility: hidden` and setting `display` other than `none` (what would required to show your element).

I used this 3 step method in a context menu component for calculating where to place the menu relative to the click position to always be on-screen:

1. set `visibility: hidden` and remove `display: none` (set to what it will be when the menu finally shown)
2. get the dimensions
3. remove `visibility: hidden`

It will probably still not work when the parent also has `display: none` but that wasn't an issue for this use case as one can not (should not) access a context menu of an object that is not shown anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this :

```
var wmd1Style = window.getComputedStyle(wmd1);
o.innerHTML = 'wmd1: "' + parseInt(wmd1Style['width'], 10) + '", "' + parseInt(wmd1Style['height'], 10) + '", wmd2: "' + wmd2.clientWidth + '", "' + wmd2.clientHeight + '"';
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a method that for some reasons **work** but, funny thing, I can't properly explain why. Basically, in my use case, I need to know the height of tabs in order to toggle them smoothly in vanilla js.

To calculate the height, I do the following steps in javascript:

1. Element is displayed but with "height:0px" and "overflow:hidden" (alternative to "display: none")
2. Set the element to "height:auto"
3. Calculate the height of the element with offsetHeight property
4. Set back the element to "height:0px"
5. Set the calculated height to the element inside a setTimeout, in combination with a css transition for smoother transition

I expected the animation to flicker but it does not. It blows my mind to be able to do this since it's probably the **most simple solution** here, but feel free to share your ideas if you understand why it works and if you see any drawbacks doing this.

```js
  function toggleTabs() {
    let tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.accordionX a span')
    tabs.forEach(tab => {
      tab.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        tab.classList.toggle('active')
        if (tab.classList.contains('active')) {
          //hide other tabs
          tabs.forEach(tab => {
            if (tab != e.target) {
              tab.classList.remove('active');
              tab.parentElement.nextElementSibling.style.height = '0px';
            }
          })
          var tabContent = tab.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
          tabContent.style.height = 'auto';
          var tabHeight = tabContent.offsetHeight + 'px'
          tabContent.style.height = '0px';
          setTimeout(function() {tabContent.style.height = tabHeight}, 15)
        } else {
          tab.classList.remove('active');
          tab.parentElement.nextElementSibling.style.height = '0px';
        }
      })
    })
  } toggleTabs();
```

```css
.accordionX{margin:0px 20px}
.accordionX > li{border-bottom:1px solid #e7e7e7;position:relative;list-style-type:none}
.accordionX > li:first-child{border-top:1px solid #e7e7e7}
.accordionX > li a::after{display:none}
.accordionX > li p{color:#3c3c3b;line-height:1.8;text-align:left}
.accordionX > li > a span{position:relative;color:#3c3c3b;padding-right:5%;display:block;cursor:pointer;font-weight:600;line-height:3;text-indent:15px;user-select:none;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent;border:none!important}
.accordionX > li > a span:after{width:8px;height:8px;border-right:1px solid #3c3c3b;border-bottom:1px solid #3c3c3b;position:absolute;right:18px;top:25px;content:" ";top:50%;transform:translate(0,-50%) rotate(-45deg);-webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;-moz-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;transition:all .2s ease-in-out}
.accordionX > li > a span > img {vertical-align: middle;margin-right: 10px;}
.accordionX p{font-size:1em;padding:10px 15px 0}
.accordionX > li > a span.active:after{transform:translate(0,-75%) rotate(45deg);-webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;-moz-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;transition:all .2s ease-in-out}
.accordionX .in-accordion{box-sizing:content-box;overflow:hidden;height:0px;transition:height .4s ease 0.1s}
.accordionX .in-accordion li {list-style: disc;list-style-position: inside;}
.accordionX .in-accordion p:last-child{padding-bottom:20px}
```

```html
<ul class="accordionX">
    <li>
        <a id="tab1">
            <span>TAB 1</span>
        </a>
        <div class="in-accordion" style="height: 0px;">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit placerat vestibulum at, leo torquent arcu tortor lectus gravida commodo neque elementum, semper posuere libero tincidunt velit vulputate morbi iaculis lacinia.
            </p>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a id="tab2">
            <span>TAB 2</span>
        </a>
        <div class="in-accordion" style="height: 0px;">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit placerat vestibulum at, leo torquent arcu tortor lectus gravida commodo neque elementum, semper posuere libero tincidunt velit vulputate morbi iaculis lacinia. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet consectetur adipiscing elit placerat vestibulum at, leo torquent arcu tortor lectus gravida commodo neque elementum, semper posuere libero tincidunt velit vulputate morbi iaculis lacinia. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                consectetur adipiscing elit placerat vestibulum at, leo torquent arcu tortor lectus gravida commodo neque elementum, semper posuere libero tincidunt velit vulputate morbi iaculis lacinia.
            </p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```