# How to get DIV size values while it is 'displayed:none', without any size values (Using javascript and CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make an effect using javascript and CSS.

When I try to get the size of a not displayed (display:none) DIV I get 0px width and 0px height.

accpetMessageContainer have 'display: none' when I try to get its size.

```
{
      var aM = document.getElementById('acceptMessageContainer'); 
      h = aM.clientHeight;
      w = aM.clientWidth;
      supp.style.width = w+'px';
      supp.style.height = h+'px';
}
```

So supp is assigned 0px width and 0px height.

Is there any way I could get the size values the DIV will have when displayed before displaying it?

I let you this code and everything else on the snippet.

If someone could lend me a hand with that, I wold be really grateful. Thank you for your time.

```js
function acceptOrDecline(id) {
  switch (id) {
    case 'accept':
    {
      if (!document.getElementById('supportLayerIn') ||!document.getElementById('supportLayerOut')) {
        var cont = document.getElementById('contentContainer');
        var w = cont.clientWidth;
        var h = cont.clientHeight;
        var layer = document.createElement('div');
        layer.id = 'supportLayerIn';
        cont.appendChild(layer);
        var supp = document.getElementById('supportLayerIn');
        supp.style.width = w+'px';
        supp.style.height = h+'px';
      }

      /**** assign the class fadeIn to supportLayerIn so it appears in front of the actual content with a fadein effect *****/
      setTimeout(function () {
        supp.classList.add('fadeIn');
      }, 1);

      supp.addEventListener('transitionend', function(e) {
        if (e.propertyName === 'visibility') {
          console.log('fadeIn finished!');
    
  /*** Here is the problem ***/
      var aM = document.getElementById('acceptMessageContainer');
        h = aM.clientHeight;
        w = aM.clientWidth;
        supp.style.width = w+'px';
        supp.style.height = h+'px';
  }

        if (e.propertyName === 'height') {
          console.log('Grow/shrink finished!');
          /***** At the end I change supportLayerIn id to 'supportLayerOut' and remove supp DIV at the end *****/
          supp.id = 'supportLayerOut';
          setTimeout(function () {
            supp.classList.add('fadeOut');
          }, 1);
          setTimeout(function () {
            cont.removeChild(supp);
          }, 501);
        }
      }, false);



      break;
    }

    case 'decline':
    {
      console.log('No thanks');
      break;
    }
    default: console.log('Does nothing...');
  }

}
```

```css
.main1 {
  max-width: 100vw;
 max-height: 100vh;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 width:100vw;
 height:100vh;
}

.wrapper {
  overflow:hidden;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
}

.contentContainer {
  position: relative;
  border: solid;
  border-color: red;
  padding: 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 7px #ccc;
  background-color: green;
}

/******************************************* Formulary ********************************************/
.formContainer {
  display: none;
}

.formContainer.active {
  display: flex;
}


/*************************************** acceptMessage container *************************************/
.acceptMessageContainer {
  display: none;
}

.acceptMessageContainer.active {
  display: flex;
}


/******************************* Hidding/showing classes **********************************/
.inactive {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}


/******************************** Support layer ****************************************/
#supportLayerIn {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear 0s, visibility 0.5s linear 0s, width 1s linear 0s, height 1s linear 0s;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: white;
}

#supportLayerIn.fadeIn {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear 0s, visibility 0.5s linear 0s;
}

.fadeIn {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear 0s, visibility 0.5s linear 0s;
}

#supportLayerOut {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear 0s, visibility 0.5s linear 0s, width 1s linear 0s, height 1s linear 0s;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: white;
}

#supportLayerOut.fadeOut {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear 0s, visibility 0.5s linear 0s;
}

.fadeOut {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear 0s, visibility 0.5s linear 0s;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main1">
      <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="contentContainer" id="contentContainer">
    <div id="acceptMessageContainer" class="acceptMessageContainer inactive">
     X
    </div>
    <div id="formContainer" class="formContainer active">
   <form id="registryForm" name="registryForm" action="">
     <button type="button" id="accept" onclick="acceptOrDecline(this.id);">Accept</button>
     <button type="button" id="decline" onclick="acceptOrDecline(this.id);">No, thanks</button>
   </form>
    </div>
  </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>



</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you find the dimensions of a "display: none" element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35519137/how-do-you-find-the-dimensions-of-a-display-none-element)

Comment: I think your problem is like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345784/jquery-get-height-of-hidden-element-in-jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first set the div to have a `display: block`, and then get the size. After that you can set it to `display:none`.

All of this happens in a few milliseconds and nothing show on the screen.

```
  var aM = document.getElementById('acceptMessageContainer'); 
  aM.style.display = "block";
  h = aM.clientHeight;
  w = aM.clientWidth;
  aM.style.display = "none";
  supp.style.width = w+'px';
  supp.style.height = h+'px';
```

Comment: This does work for me, yet I'm worried about a possible flickering effect.

Comment: Oh dont worry about that. It is very quickly, just some miliseconds. The screen will not show anything. And if it will, our eyes can not see it.

Answer (score 0):

[`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) displays dimensions of an element even in its non-visibility state.

Try this:

```
{
    var aM = document.getElementById('acceptMessageContainer'); 
    supp.style.width = window.getComputedStyle(aM).getPropertyValue("width");
    supp.style.height = window.getComputedStyle(aM).getPropertyValue("height"); 
}
```

Comment: seems like this only gives you the exact width and height set in CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.

I get 'auto' and that's because I'm not giving any size to 'acceptMessageContainer' on its style, it'll have the size it needs to fit all its content.
It would be way easier to make this using fixed size values, but that is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Does `acceptMessageContainer` have any content when the above calculations are done? If it has no content and no size is provided through css, then the values returned will be 0px I guess.

Comment: @nashcheez Yes, in this example it does just have 'X' as content, but it does have 'something'.