# Accordion Close Transition

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion

I am trying to create an accordion which has a transition when you open and close it. Unfortunately I was not able to make the close transition(the open transition works perfectly). Any suggestions?

I think I should modify the javascript code(maybe add one more "active" class), but I am not sure. I am still learning html / css / javascript so expect to find some bad code here

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("label");

for (var i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    panel.classList.toggle("opened");
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordions {
  max-width: 760px;
  width: 100%;
  gap: 35px;
}

.accordion-body {
  padding: 24px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 16px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0, 20%);
  outline: none;
}

.label {
  padding: 24px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  p {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: 0;
  }
  img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    transition: 0.25s;
  }
}

.active {
  img {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
  }
}

.accordion-content {
  padding: 24px;
  background-color: $white;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 16px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 16px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  gap: 24px;
  hr {
    margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  p {
    margin: 0;
  }
  &.opened {
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Descoperă-ți Sportul</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>

<body>
  <main class="main d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column">

    <div class="accordion-body w-100" id="faq-1">
      <button class="label d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center w-100">
            <p class="fw-bold">Why should I practice a sport as a hobby?</p>
            <img src="accordion-icon.svg" alt="icon" />
          </button>
      <div class="accordion-content">
        <hr />
        <p class="fw-medium">
          Playing a sport as a hobby can improve physical and mental health, reduce stress, improve sleep quality, help maintain a healthy weight and provide social opportunities. It can also be a great way to learn new skills and enjoy your free time.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <script src="accordionSection.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: from your code it seems you are using bootstrap. If yes then why don't you use `Accordion` component from bootstrap, you can get the job done without writing the CSS classes and JS code to manipulate styling of the accordion. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/

Comment: `display: none` that is tripping you up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35519137/how-do-you-find-the-dimensions-of-a-display-none-element You should also use js to change classes on elements, and apply CSS through close classes, instead of using js to apply CSS inline, that is difficult to override and not a good use of cascade. You could have added .label.active + .accordion-content {max-height: 1000px;} Also read https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/

Comment: @santra72 I find it difficult to style in the way I want

Comment: @prkos if I set the display: block (for example), it will make my accordion open by default and I dont want this. Sorry for not saying this sooner

Comment: The content will not be visible because initially you have max-height: 0; you should also add overflow: hidden;